# Aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing this statement in MS ACCESS

```
SELECT tblTrades.Tick, Sum(tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast) AS SumOfBBG_Div_Forecast, tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date
FROM tblBbgDivData INNER JOIN tblTrades ON tblBbgDivData.Tick = tblTrades.Tick
GROUP BY tblTrades.Tick
HAVING (((tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date) Between [tblTrades].[vd_off] And [tblTrades].[vd_on]));
```

--> you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Div_Declared_Date' as an aggregate function

I have tried to change the <> with Between, same thing!

Comment: You have `Div_Declared_Date` in the SELECT list but not in a `GROUP BY`, MS Access will not allow that functionality.  If you need to include `Div_Declared_Date` in the SELECT list, then you need to use an aggregate function for it or add it to your GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your problems highlighted below. From the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx):

> Summary values are omitted if there is no SQL aggregate function in
>   the SELECT statement.
>
> Null values in GROUP BY fields are grouped and are not omitted.
>   However, Null values are not evaluated in any SQL aggregate function.
>
> **Use the WHERE clause to exclude rows you do not want grouped, and use
>   the HAVING clause to filter records after they have been grouped.**
>
> Unless it contains Memo or OLE Object data, a field in the GROUP BY
>   field list can refer to any field in any table listed in the FROM
>   clause, even if the field is not included in the SELECT statement,
>   provided the SELECT statement includes at least one SQL aggregate
>   function. The Microsoft Access database engine cannot group on Memo or
>   OLE Object fields.
>
> **All fields in the SELECT field list must either be included in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be included as arguments to an SQL aggregate
>   function.**

So your query should be:

```
SELECT tblTrades.Tick,
  Sum(tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast) AS SumOfBBG_Div_Forecast,
  tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date
FROM tblBbgDivData
INNER JOIN tblTrades
  ON tblBbgDivData.Tick = tblTrades.Tick
WHERE (((tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date) BETWEEN [tblTrades].[vd_off] AND [tblTrades].[vd_on]));
GROUP BY tblTrades.Tick,tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date
```

Answer (score -2):

Having is used for checking aggregated columns (after aggregation).  So if you wanted to know that the sum of tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast was greater than 500, you would use
`HAVING SUM(tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast) > 500`

You need to move it to your where clause:

```
SELECT tblTrades.Tick, Sum(tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast) AS SumOfBBG_Div_Forecast, tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date
FROM tblBbgDivData INNER JOIN tblTrades ON tblBbgDivData.Tick = tblTrades.Tick
WHERE (((tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date) Between [tblTrades].[vd_off] And [tblTrades].[vd_on]))
GROUP BY tblTrades.Tick
;
```

Answer (score -2):

`HAVING` only works with aggrecate functions to limit the results based on a formula applied to each group.  I think you want `WHERE`:

```
SELECT tblTrades.Tick, Sum(tblBbgDivData.BBG_Div_Forecast) AS SumOfBBG_Div_Forecast, tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date
FROM tblBbgDivData INNER JOIN tblTrades ON tblBbgDivData.Tick = tblTrades.Tick
WHERE (((tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date) Between [tblTrades].[vd_off] And [tblTrades].[vd_on]));
GROUP BY tblTrades.Tick
```

You also have a field in your `SELECT` statement (`tblBbgDivData.Div_Declared_Date`) that is not in oyur `GROUP BY`, so you'll either need to group by that field also or apply an aggergation to it